# how to develop grouped stack bar chart using crossfilter and dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

[image: Grouped Stacked bar chart(Sample)]

```
stackedbarchart.width(460)
                .height(250)
                .margins({top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 20, left: 10})
                .dimension(stackedbarchartDimension)
                .group(stackedbarchartGroup)
                .stack(stackedbarchartGroup_stack)
                .stack(stackedbarchartGroup_stack2)
                .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
                .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
```

Please, Post any working example for 'Grouped stacked bar' chart using dc.js.

Comment: Hi @Ashutosh, sorry but this is the wrong kind of question for SO. I removed a couple of vague tags that are likely to bring wrath and down/close votes. I'm not sure what you mean by "passing numeric value" - those methods [take a group and an optional name and accessor](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.stackMixin.html#stack__anchor) as arguments. There are [at least one](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/stacked-bar.html) or [two](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/crime/index.html) examples of stacked bar on the site.

Comment: I'm sure you can find many more examples - just [google dc.js stacked bar](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=dc.js%20stacked%20bar)!

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for your reply. But, i don't need Stacked bar chart needed Grouped stacked bar chart. Sample screen-shots, i have added and edited question. please, check and share any working example for Grouped stacked bar chart.

Comment: Got it - that does make sense as an SO question then, although it's not too hard to search and find the answer I gave below.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't part of the core library yet, but there is an active pull request which you can use:

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1459

There is a built version on a branch, so if you are using npm, you can specify the dependency

```
"dc": "git://github.com/dc-js/dc.js.git#grouped-stacked-3",
```

Or just clone the repo and use the `grouped-stacked-3` branch.

The branch contains these examples:

```
web/examples/bar-grouped-multi.html
web/examples/bar-grouped.html
```

**EDIT:** That's wild, I see it still doesn't have an example of grouped+stacked bars. I'll see if I can fix that; until then I think [this plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/GEdCVUjc3I1UPhUX?p=preview&preview) is the best example

[image: grouped stacked]

Comment: Thanks @Gordan .
But, this is not the perfect one what i needed. You can check the screen-shot.
I already checked that grouped chart whatever you have shared. Please share any working example for Grouped stacked bar chart

Comment: What's wrong with it? I don't know of any other implementation, sorry.

Comment: I don't know, how you are not getting my point. There should be two level of nested dimension and grouped in each section, you can check in screen-shots.
Better check this link http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=bars_vertical_grouped_stacked (Example of Stacked grouped bar chart)

Comment: Check the example plunkr. It is both grouped and stacked. Maybe the gap between groups should be larger but yes it is both. I got your point!

Comment: Thank you. 
Again, I checked plunkr. There are separate chart either Stackedbar chart or grouped bar chart. I need both(Grouped and stacked) in one chart only that is why i wrote chart name as Grouped stacked bar chart and shared the screenshots.

Comment: I did a couple of minor changes to the plunkr to show it better. I think with ticks only on the hours, with a larger gap between groups, and with colors similar to your example, it should be more clear what functionality is offered. I'm sure there is still more that could be improved, so if you try it out, please leave any feedback on the GitHub PR.

Comment: @Gordon To funny that I just found this.  I am also attempting to implement a Group Stacked chart and was going to try and use the SeriesChart.  We just added a Series chart w/ LineCharts and thought it might also work for StackedBars.  Is Composite or Series the way to go or should I look at upgrading to 3.x

Comment: Hi @ChrisWolcott, it is possible to implement a grouped stacked bar chart just using the series / composite chart but it's tricky. The PR linked above basically includes those tricks and fixes. It's not ready to merge (see the discussion for why) but I've been keeping a couple of branches fairly up to date, so please try it out and comment on GH!